# Cant use bones on differnt part of mesh

Tags: mesh, bones

When I connect my bones to the mesh, I want to use surtan bones to move a surtan part of a mesh, I have 2 bones and one of them is for the arm and one for the leg, how do I allow the bones to only move a part of a mesh at a time?

Comment: your question is too large, it would take too long to explain everything about rigging, you should follow some tutorials about it on youtube

Comment: You need to parent the mesh to the armature "With automatic weights". BTW, what's surtan? Do you mean "certain"?